# Conditionally populate React Container From URL Parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I don't know exactly how to approach this problem, and my research is turning up conflicting/confusing information. I'm using react, redux, saga, and react-router.

I have basically a master/detail scenario. I present the user with a list of stories and when they click on one, it loads a detail component with the details read from the state. However, I want users to be able to deep-link to the detail page if they know the detail ID. http://localhost:3000/story/1496620859347.

I am dispatching an action triggered in the component constructor, but the state that is mapped to the component props never changes. What am I doing wrong? (I've added some of the component code, but I'm not sure it is relevant.)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import './FullStory.css';
import he from 'he';
import { downloadSelectedStoryByID } from '../store/actions/selected_story';

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>  {  
  return {
    story: state.selected_story
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {  
  return {
    getStoryByID(id) {
      dispatch(downloadSelectedStoryByID(id));
    }
  } 
} 

class FullStory extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    if (props.story.id == undefined) {
        this.props.getStoryByID(props.match.params.id);
    }

  }
  render() {
    return ( 

 )
```

**Reducer**

import c from '../../constants';

```
export const selected_story = (state={}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
        case c.DOWNLOAD_STORY_BY_ID_SUCCEEDED:        
          return action.payload;
        case c.SET_SELECTED_STORY:
          return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I put in the reducer.

Comment: Can you post the entire code.Render function is missing here and the reducers as well.